# VertexAI's class AutoMLtabularTrainingJob doesn't recognize parameters listed in the documentation

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to create a prediction model using the VertexAI class AutoMLtabularTrainingJob, and I'm having problems with two parameters listed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform.AutoMLTabularTrainingJob).

First, the parameter column_specs is a dictionary in the documentation, and the parameter export_evaluated_data_items is a bool.

I created the function below, and I called it inside a loop.

```
def create_training_pipeline_tabular_regression_sample(
display_name:str,
dataset_id:int,
column_specs:dict,
target_column:str = None,
optimization_prediction_type:str = 'regression',
optimization_objective:str = 'minimize-rmse',
model_display_name:str = None,
budget_milli_node_hours:int = 1000,
disable_early_stopping:bool = False,
export_evaluated_data:bool = True,
sync:bool = True,
**kwargs
):

tabular_regression_job = aiplatform.AutoMLTabularTrainingJob(
    display_name=display_name,
    column_specs=column_specs,
    optimization_prediction_type=optimization_prediction_type,
    optimization_objective=optimization_objective
)

my_tabular_dataset = aiplatform.TabularDataset(dataset_id)

model = tabular_regression_job.run(
    dataset=my_tabular_dataset,
    target_column=target_column,
    budget_milli_node_hours=budget_milli_node_hours,
    model_display_name=model_display_name,
    disable_early_stopping=disable_early_stopping,
    export_evaluated_data_items=True,
    sync=sync,
    **kwargs
)

model.wait()

print(model.display_name)
print(model.resource_name)
print(model.uri)
return model
```

The error is that the class is not accepting these parameters. The error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_118/330955058.py in <module>
     60                     optimization_objective=optimization,
     61                     budget_milli_node_hours= BUDGET_MILLI_NODE_HOURS,
---> 62                     export_evaluated_data_items_bigquery_destination_uri=export_evaluated_data_items_bigquery_destination_uri
     63                 )
     64 

/tmp/ipykernel_118/2971171495.py in create_training_pipeline_tabular_regression_sample(display_name, dataset_id, target_column, optimization_prediction_type, optimization_objective, model_display_name, budget_milli_node_hours, disable_early_stopping, export_evaluated_data, sync, **kwargs)
     31         export_evaluated_data_items=True,
     32         sync=sync,
---> 33         **kwargs
     34     )
     35 

TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'export_evaluated_data_items'
```

Does anyone know if the documentation is updated? In the page's footer the update date is recent, but these errors make me have doubts. And there's other information in the documentation that does not match with the API's use.

Comment: I have tried your given code and was able to finish the training. What is the version of your AI Platform on your python environment?

Comment: The version is 0.7.1, what's yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error when I downgraded to google-cloud-aiplatform version `0.7.1`. To resolve this, you must update your version to the latest **google-cloud-aiplatform** package by using the below command.

```
pip install google-cloud-aiplatform --upgrade
```

You will now have **google-cloud-aiplatform** version `1.13.1`.

[image]

Once upgraded to the latest version, you can now proceed and finish your training.
[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! I upgraded the lib version and it's working now! When the problems started it didn't even cross my mind to check the version I have installed. I'll pay more attention to that in the future.